# Can you change the default clock format?

Tags: big-sur, time

I want to change this
[image]

to a more standard format dd/mm/yyyy.

I have looked in the date/time settings and changed the formats
[image]

But that didn't seem to change a thing.
Is that possible in MacOS Big Sur?

Comment: The preference that you want to alter is Preferences->Doc&Menu Bar->Clock - but that only allows you to show the short day of week or none :(

Comment: thanks.  and oh that is frustrating, the only options I currently have there is to 'show the day of the week' or 'show date'

Comment: If you use iStatMenus (which costs) for other reasons then you can get it to show the date in the format you want

Comment: thanks, I shall take a look.  seems a bit of a shame that you have to buy an extension to do something that seems relatively simple to do